# DBUnit Boolean value

Tags: postgresql, dbunit, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

After learning SpringBoot, I wanted go further to handle integration tests using (DBUnit and SpringTestDBUnit). Throughout the process, everything was going well until I came across setting values for boolean datatyped columns on the dataset. (Contents of the dataset is given below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <Client code="0001" name="client_one" />
    <Client code="0002" name="client_two" />
    <Client code="0003" name="client_three" active="false" />
    <Client code="0004" name="client_four" />
</dataset>
```

Adding `active="false"` attribute to Client record [code=0003], my integration tests fails and showing me this message `Exception processing table name='Client'` which was resulted the Client record [code=0001] violates the active not null column constraint.

After fixing the error (on branch [DBUnit_For_Boolean_Columns_Attempt_One](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/springbootdbunitbooleantest/branch/DBUnit_For_Boolean_Columns_Attempt_One#diff)) by supplying values for active column on all records (which is a bit off the specification), it worked. But my target was able to run the integration tests successfully with the dataset written above.

The question is **how can the integration tests be successful using the dataset above?** As of now, I'm having a hard time implementing solutions so I've created a [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/springbootdbunitbooleantest/) for you to see and help on-hand.

---

**Changelogs**

- 2015/02/04 changes

  1. Improve question contents
  2. Added Bitbucket repository

Answer (score 1):

(I had a different answer here, which came from a complete misdiagnosis of the issue, as I missed the fact OP was using [`FlatXmlDataSet`](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/FlatXmlDataSet.html)).

From [`FlatXmlDataSet`](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/FlatXmlDataSet.html)'s documentation:

> Table metadata is deduced from the first row of each table by default. Beware that DbUnit may think a table misses some columns if the first row of that table has one or more `null` values.

This seems to be the issue here, as the first entry does not specify a value for `active`. To avoid this problem, you can use DBUnit's column sensing property, which essentially makes DBUnit read the entire XML before deducing the table's structure:

```
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
builder.setInputSource(new File("path/to/dataSet.xml"));
builder.setColumnSensing(true); // HERE!
IDataSet dataSet = builder.build();
```

Alternatively, if you aren't creating the builder yourself and do not want to manipulate it, just make sure to have the `active` column in every element, especially the first one:

```
<dataset>
    <client code="0001" name="client_one" active="false" />
    <client code="0002" name="client_two" active="true" />
</dataset>
```

Comment: I see. So where should I place the value `true` or `false` to the column (for example: `active`)? Should it be written on the `dataSet.xml` as `<Table active="<value>true</value>">`? I forgot to mention, I don't have an `application-context.xml` since I'm using SpringBoot

Comment: But what if this boolean column can be set to null?

Comment: @KaidoShugo You can use `<null /> instead of `<value>`, see my edited answer for an example.

Comment: After trying your solution for the first attempt. It returned me a `NoSuchTableException: value`. How is this error possible?

Comment: @KaidoShugo Are you sure you followed the example exactly? Because, as you said, you should not get such an exception. Can you please share your xml so I can see what's wrong?

Comment: @KaidoShugo I now see I was missing the closing `</table>` tag. Please try to add it and check if that was the issue.

Comment: Yes. Anyways, can I ask why is the structure of the dataset if different from the one I've given on my question?

Comment: @KaidoShugo Oh, now I see it. You were using [FlatDataSet](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/FlatXmlDataSet.html). My example uses [XmlDataSet](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/XmlDataSet.html).

Comment: @KaidoShugo I **completely** missed the problem there. I edited my post with a solution for `FlatDataSet`, which also explained what the issue was.

Comment: So is the `FlatXmlDataSetBuilder` going to be declared a bean? Or is it a standalone?

Comment: @KaidoShugo that's completely orthogonal to the problem - as long as you can control `setColumnSensing(true)` (e.g., by property injection in a bean), you should be fine.

Comment: I'll try to create a sample project repository for reference. Maybe you could help me there.

Comment: I have placed a Bitbucket repository, hope you could see it soon.